# TimelineItem id vs. sourceItemId

Tags: google-mirror-api

If two timeline items are inserted with the same sourceItemId the mirror api creates a second timeline item and does not automatically update the first.  Is it correct that I must store the mirror api timeline id after insert and map that to the sourceItemId on creation and then use update or patch to modify the item later?  How are others maintaining consistency between the mirror data and app data?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `sourceItemId` is fully in your control and there might be use-cases where you want multiple timeline items with the same `sourceItemId`(for example for multiple comments referring to the same article) therefore the Mirror API doesn't check this parameter.

Mapping timeline ids to your `sourceItemId` in your datastore is probably the best and most efficient solution.

Alternatively you can use the `timeline.list` method, which allows searching for all items with a specified `sourceItemId`, and update the existing timeline item when found, or create a new one otherwise. https://developers.google.com/glass/v1/reference/timeline/list

With the currently rather limited API quota you will want to avoid the second solution though.

Comment: Thanks, this worked. I had my head wrapped around the id/sourceItemId for a while, and got it solved.